# How to hide query string using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I redirect the 301 link to the new url is added query string, I want to hide or delete it, what should I do.
My .htaccess like :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?mod=mod&cmd=$1 [L]

    Redirect 301 /category1.html http://example.com/list/category1
```

And result : `http://example.com/list/category1?mod=mod&cmd=list/category1`

I want it to show up like this : `http://example.com/list/category1`

Thanks all.